# Debug GWT application on server side

Tags: gwt

I want to know how to debug the GWT application on server side. I am using eclipse and GWT default server. I run my application by right click and run as web application. I tried to use System.out.println and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to debug the GWT servercode? This works like every other JavaApp.

Comment: Yes. So you mean System.out.println should work? I actually had a hard time understanding activities, places and MVP and finally got it. Now, I want to see whether my request is going to the server, so I put a trace on the server. When I click on the submit, I only see this :[WARN] 404 - POST /smartebrm/client (127.0.0.1) 1402 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      Connection: keep-alive
      Content-Length: 232
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/smartebrm/
      X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode

Comment: @gagan This is telling you your mapping in the `web.xml` is wrong for the RPC servlet (or the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` is wrong, but in any case there's a mismatch)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I had a problem in the servlet path. I am migrating my project from jsps to GWT. My jsp project is currently working on Tomcat, where I load some records from database when server starts, and keep them in cache. Can I do the same with Google default server also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the embedded server of DevMode, then it works just like for client-side: *Debug as… ⇒ Web Application* then set your breakpoints (either client-side or server-side, they run in the same JVM).

When you change your server-side code, Eclipse will recompile it on-the-fly (unless you disabled it, in which case you'll have to explicitly build your project) into your `WEB-INF/classes` (this is what the GPE should configure), then hit the "reload" button on the DevMode view in Eclipse (the two yellow arrows). The next call from the client to server will use the new server code (without the need to reload the app in the browser).
If Eclipse proposes to hot-swap the code on change, you can say "no".

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to run in `debug` mode.

Right click on the project -> **Debug As** -> Web application

[image]

OR you can follow below steps also.

Click on `Debug As..` as shown in toolbar of Eclipse -> Debug configuration -> Debug

[image]

[image]